# How to parse XML contained in a string to an IList<BusinessObject>?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing

I have the following XML in a string:

```
<RootElement>
  <Data>
    <Row>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Foo</name>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>Bar</name>
    </Row>
       .
       .
       .
  </Data>
</RootElement>
```

And the following class:

```
public class BusinessObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How can i parse all the data in the Row elements to an IList ( in C# ) ?
I searched the internet a few hours but couldn't find anything to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option, using LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(...);
var businessObjects = doc.Descendants("Row")
                         .Select(x => new BusinessObject {
                                     Id = (int) x.Element("id"),
                                     Name = (string) x.Element("name")
                                 })
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: shouldn't Id be converted to an integer?

Comment: Using Linq to parse XML rocks!